Is there any way that I can draw the chart in Python?
the image I wanted to draw but i mimicked by hands
I tried to draw this type of chart but Sankey or stacked bar chart cannot be a solution for this.
As time goes, sum of the values of each category varies and
each entity can change its attribute so the sum of the entities (which makes the value of each category) can vary also.
Sankey is partially right and it is sorta affordable if I normalize the values
but I want to show exactly this one.
it is the graph I want to draw.

Please show what you tried in a minimal example code. Why does a Sankey chart not fit your need?

If I understand correctly, I think what you want to achieve can be achieved with a Sankey diagrams, just have straight lines instead of bending ones? I'm quite sure you can change the lines' parameter to be straight. I've already seen such a bipartite diagram. Probably was created in D3.js (Blocks), but D3Blocks also has a Python library, likely that is a way to go.

@StephanT I cannot achieve the result above with Sankey, because it is impossible to increase or decrease the flow between the nodes. Sankey in, for example, plotly assumed that the amount would not change between nodes. For the bank loan from Y1 to Y2, if the amount borrowed by the vulnerables increased from 300 to 500. Among this, 'the previous vulnerables' increased from 250 to 350, and 'the newly vulnerables', who were not 'vulnerable' in Y1, stayed at same at 150. ('the newly non-vulnerables' could be increased from 50 to 100 then the calculation is right.)

You are referring to "bank loans", "Y1" etc but none of that is clear in your question. Please provide a minimized dataset which contains the essence of the problem.
